# Maximum length of **argv parameters

Tags: c, posix

On POSIX-like systems, is there a maximum length for command line arguments?

To clarify, I'm looking for the maximum length of *each* command line argument, not the maximum number of arguments.

Comment: Here is a very detailed investigation into the matter: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ I won't repost the information here as it'll have to be summarised and rephrased, and this is quite a complex issue.

Comment: I suspect its highly platform specific. you can instead pass data to your program through stdin if its a lot of data.

Comment: No, _POXIX_ARG_MAX is the maximum length for all arguments together.

Answer (score 7):

POSIX doesn't define a maximum length for each argument.

`MAX_ARG_STRLEN` is a Linux-specific constant [which was introduced in the 2.6.25 kernel](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-make@gnu.org/msg05522.html).

As of the 2.6.25 kernel, `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` is defined as `131072 bytes`=`32 pages of memory`.

(I'm assuming a pagesize of 4k, which is the case unless `CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE` is enabled. I'm not sure how `CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE` affects `MAX_ARG_STRLEN`.)

See also: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man2/execve.2.html

Comment: cnicutar, sorry my original question was unclear and thanks for answering. Your answer helped me research mine.